# Map user to default schema in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I had a new DB and I created a new user (ElarabyGroup) owner for this DB. And when I tried to map this user for default schema but I did not the name of object in browse of objects window.

Please any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but to set the default schema for a user you can use:

```
ALTER USER SomeUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = SomeSchema
```

You can find complete information about users and schemas here (check out the catalog views and examples in particular):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387(v=SQL.90).aspx